# Amazon Glacier Job Inventory Download Not Available

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

I run the following through the AWS CLI interface.

```
aws glacier list-jobs --account-id=xxxxx --vault-name=MyVault
```

And I get a list of jobs I have requested for Glacier. I currently have a Vault Inventory job that is Complete.

I then run this, to get the job.

```
aws glacier get-job-output --account-id=xxxx --vault-name=MyVault --job-id=TheEXACT_CopyAndPasted_JobID_From_The_Above_Output outfile=temp.txt
```

And I get an error.

"ResourceNotFoundException". The job ID was not found.

What gives? The Job is listed in the list-jobs command. And it is Completed (even if not completed you get a different not yet ready error).

It has been many hours since the job completed.

Does Amazon delete the job output BEFORE deleting the list of available jobs?

I KNOW the job ID is correct, because I can download a more recent job inventory request.  It seems that they deleted my JobID from the 'succeeded' jobs (and thus is not really available for inventory download), but did NOT delete the job from the list-jobs database.

Is this a known error? Because it makes error checking more important for my scripts if I can list jobs as 'succeeded' and available when really they aren't.

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: This is happening for me too.  Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: It might be due to delay in time the inventory becomes available, wait about a day and re-try. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/vault-inventory.html